# I don't understand how to design project's schema in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode5

I must design schema's project of courses e-learning available on line for APP IOS.

I have four entity

1. USER
2. COURSE SUBSCRIBED
3. SECTION and
4. MODULE

For each entity there are some `attributes` for example in the USER entity there is "username". I think that don't have to implement design like relational DB. I don't undestand how to do.

**The problem is:** if I have an entity USER with attribute username and entity COURSE SUBSCRIBED the relationship is `(a to many)` because an user can subscribed more courses, therefore in the entity COURSE SUBSCRIBED,

- should I have also the field username like normaly I use in relational DB?
- Or is it possible to insert an attribute (courses) that identifies which courses subscribed by a user in entity USER ?

Because I will be able to have more users and each user could have more courses, then I will have to be able to show to show to which courses is registered each user.
How to do by `CORE DATA`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-TP1) or [THAT](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)?

Comment: yes but I don't understand